Derivation in "Step-by-Step... HHL" is unclear
In the excellent paper "Step-by-Step HHL Algorithm Walkthough..., https://arxiv.org/abs/2108.09004, it makes a derivation that is not clear to me at all.
In Equation (15) it combines the effect of phase estimation and the inverse QFT into this close form:
$$
\frac{1}{2^n} |b\rangle \sum_{y=0}^{2^n-1} \sum_{k=0}^{2^n-1} e^{2 \pi i k(\phi - y/N)} |y\rangle |0\rangle
$$
So far so good, this just combines the closed form of QPE with $QFT^{-1}$.  Then it says that only $|y\rangle$ for which is $\phi - y/N = 0$ will have an amplitude, all other amplitudes are 0. I know this is correct, because that's how it works during QPE, but I have difficulties deriving this result in this closed form.
In the next step (Equation 16), it further arrives at $|b\rangle |N \phi\rangle |0\rangle$, which is even more unclear to me. I'm not sure I understand what $|N \phi\rangle$ is supposed to mean here?
Any help with a precise derivation (actually step-by-step ;-) would be greatly appreciated.

Write
\begin{align}
    \frac{1}{2^n} \sum_{y=0}^{2^n-1} \sum_{k=0}^{2^n-1} e^{2 \pi i k(\phi - y/N)} |y\rangle  =  \sum_{y=0}^{2^n-1} \left(\frac{1}{2^n} \sum_{k=0}^{2^n-1} e^{2 \pi i k(\phi - y/N)}\right) |y\rangle.
\end{align}
The stuff in the parentheses is just a coefficient of $|y\rangle$.
Suppose for some $y_0$, we have $\phi - y_0/N = 0$, then the coefficient of $|y_0\rangle$ is
$$\left(\frac{1}{2^n} \sum_{k=0}^{2^n-1} e^{2 \pi i k(\phi - y_0/N)}\right) = \left(\frac{1}{2^n} \sum_{k=0}^{2^n-1} e^{2 \pi i k0}\right) = \frac{2^n}{2^n} = 1.$$
Since $\phi - y_0/N =0$, we can solve for $y_0$,
\begin{align}
\phi - y_0/N &=0\\
\phi &= y_0/N\\
\phi N &= y_0.
\end{align}
So we have $|y_0 \rangle = |\phi N\rangle$.
Addendum:
Even though this was not part of the question, I added it for completeness.
If $\phi - y/N \neq 0$, then
$$\sum_{k=0}^{2^n-1} e^{2 \pi i k(\phi - y/N)} =0.$$
This follows from the geometric series formula:
$$1 + \alpha + \alpha^2 + \ldots + \alpha^{n-1} = \begin{cases}
\frac{1-\alpha^n}{1-\alpha}, \text{ if } \alpha \neq 1\\
n, \text{ if } \alpha =1
\end{cases}$$
Therefore, if $\phi - y/N \neq 0$, then $\alpha:=e^{2\pi i (\phi - y/N)} \neq 1$. It follows that
$$\sum_{k=0}^{2^n-1} e^{2 \pi i k(\phi - y/N)} = \frac{1-e^{2\pi i (\phi - y/N)2^n}}{1-e^{2\pi i (\phi - y/N)}} = 0.$$
This is because we can write
$$1-e^{2\pi i (\phi - y/N)2^n} = 1 - (e^{2\pi i 2^n})^{\phi - y/N} = 1 - (1)^{\phi - y/N} = 0.$$

Wonderful, Thanks! This explains most of my question. Still not clear why for cases where $\phi - y_0/N \ne 0$, the coefficient would be 0?

Hint: Quantum states have a unit norm. If one of the coefficients is 1, what does it leave for the rest of coefficients?

MonteNero - you rock ;-) (Thanks)

@rhundt, I've added something extra if you are after a more rigorous argument.

I'd just add how an amplitude of $|y \rangle$ behaves over $(\phi - y/N)$.
$ \sum_{k=0}^{2^n-1} e^{2 \pi i k(\phi - y/N)} \tag{1}$
Let $(\phi - y/N)$ be $\alpha$ then $(1)$ can be written as :
$ \sum_{k=0}^{2^n-1} e^{2 \pi i k\alpha} \tag{2}$
When $\alpha$(=$\phi - y/N$) is integer, e.g. 0, an amplitude becomes a finite value. When alpha is not integer an amplitude converges to 0 due to destructive interference. The diagram below shows the result of geometric sum of (2).
n = 6 (qubits) is used in the diagram:

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

n = 6    # num of qubits
N = 2**n # N = 2^n
alpha_vals = np.linspace(0, 2, 1000) # this is phi - y/N

def geom_sum(alpha, N):
    #import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
    k = np.arange(N)
    sum = np.exp(2j * np.pi * k * alpha)  # e^(2pi * i * k * alpha)
    return np.abs(np.sum(sum))

# calculate the sum for each alpha
sums = [geom_sum(alpha, N) for alpha in alpha_vals]

# Plot the results
plt.figure(figsize=(10, 6))
plt.plot(alpha_vals, sums, label=f'Sum with N={N}')
plt.axhline(y=N, color='r', linestyle='--', label='Constructive Interference (alpha integer)')
plt.xlabel('Alpha (α)')
plt.ylabel('|Sum|')
plt.title('Behavior of the Sum for Non-integer and Integer alpha')
plt.legend()
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()

